# Android - Cant cancel alarm set in UnCaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: android, task, alarmmanager

I am using an Alarm Manager and have put this into my code to prevent the alarm manager from stopping when someone exits the app with a taskkiller. The problem is if the user wants to cancel the alarm it doesnt work and the alarm still goes off.

Below is the code to prevent the alarm from being stopped when the app is killed

```
public Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler getUncaughtExceptionHandler() {

    am = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, pi);
    System.exit(2);
    return null;
}
```

Below is the code that kills the alarm intentionally

```
 if(pi != null){
        am.cancel(pi);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "All Alarms Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You have no Alarms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

pi (pending intent) and am are both set as global variables.